# Drupal 8 - What is the format for viewsreference arguments?

Tags: views

I am using a [views reference field](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference) inside a paragraph on a node. I know that I may add optional arguments but how should I format the arguments? Two things I would like to do are: 
 - Limit the number of results returned in the view to 3
 - Display only results with a certain taxonomy term

Here is a screenshot of the arguments field in the paragraphs UI.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm see code `ViewsReferenceFieldFormatter.php`.

The argument field is treated as follows:

```
if (preg_match('/\//', $argument)) {
  $arguments = explode('/', $argument);
}
```

Hence argument have next format: `tid/nid/custom_id`